# Hoje é 1º de setembro de 2015

Tags: ortografia, números

Devemos sempre empregar a forma numérica ordinal para o primeiro dia de cada mês?

Exemplo

> Hoje é 1º de setembro de 2015.

Neste caso, é um erro comum escrever da forma seguinte?

> Brasilia-DF, 1 de setembro de 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trecho desse [link](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/nao-tropece-detail.php?id=361):

> ### DIA PRIMEIRO
>
> **Pergunta**:
>
> Como é a forma correta de "Dada e passada nesta cidade do Rio Grande, aos dois dias do mês de agosto de dois mil e dois" ao se tratar do primeiro dia do mês? César Almeida Lehn, Rio Grande/RS
>
> **Resposta:**
>
> O equivalente a “aos dois dias, aos três dias do mês...” (fórmula usada em atas e alguns documentos oficiais) é: ”Dada e passada nesta cidade do Rio Grande, no primeiro dia do mês de agosto de dois mil e dois”.
>
> Tanto é assim que a **norma oficial** para escrever essa mesma data em algarismos é 1º de agosto de 2009 (e não 01 ou 1), que se lê primeiro de agosto.
>
> Aproveito para lembrar que a indicação do ano não deve conter ponto entre a casa do milhar e a da centena: 1822, 1999, 2010 (e não 2.010).